# T-SQL COALESCE in AdventureWorks2012 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

So I've been messing around trying to learn SQL using AW2012 database and I came across something that doesn't make sense to me.

I am trying to learn the COALESCE Statement from using the Person.Person table and when I type:

```
SELECT Title, COALESCE (FirstName, LastName) AS FullName 
FROM Person.Person;
```

All I get in the result box is the Title column and the FullName column BUT the FullName is only showing the FirstName results in there. I thought COALESCE is supposed to combine FirstName and LastName into FullName? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Yep. Looks like you got confused with `COALESCE` and `CONCAT`

Comment: "*thought COALESCE is supposed to combine FirstName and LastName*" - whoever told you that was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for CONCAT, not COALESCE

COALESCE will take the first expression if it isn´t NULL.. but if it is NULL t will take the second expression, if that one is not NULL and if both are NULL, it returns NULL

CONCAT will build firstname + lastname